# Prove that $\lambda_\max (yy^*)=\|y\|^2_2$

Tags: normed-spaces

Problem: Let $y\in \mathbb{C}^n$, prove that $\lambda_{\max}(yy^*)=\|y\|^2_2$ where $y^*=\overline{y^T}, \|y\|^2_2=y^*y.$

I know that $\|y\|_2$ is an e-value of $yy^*$ since $(yy^*)y=\|y\|_2y$, but I could not go further. Help me, Thanks!

Comment: Hint: what is the rank of $yy^*$? What is it's trace?

Comment: yeah I know that  $rank(yy*)=1$ and $trace (yy^*)=\|y\|_2$, but then what can we have? @Leo

Comment: Rank 1 implies only one non-zero eigenvalue. The trace is the sum of all eigenvalues.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @NgChloe You should answer your own question, and accept it. That way, other people can benefit from the insight you've gained.